# Skype problems with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, skype

Whenever I run skype on ubuntu 14.04 with the most recent kernel, I get around 7000 ms roundtrip ping, and it's impossible to have a call with it, and it also wrecks my latency.
However, whenever I run skype on a laptop with ubuntu 15.04, and the 3.19 kernel, it runs fine, and does not affect my internet.
I have tried a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 and the problem persisted, and I have tested to see if its other computers causing the problem, it is not.
And I did not have this problem with windows.
So it seems to be a problem affecting the 14.04 release, I am new to ubuntu, and I would like to know why this is happening as well as how to fix it